# How to protect EC2 machine from being accessed via key-pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

1. Launch an EC2 instance
2. Create a separate key-pair for SSH access
3. Provide this key-pair to few developers (say dev1, dev2, dev3)
4. dev3 leaves the company
5. How to revoke permissions for a dev3 user in such a case

Comment: Do you have to use SSH? What about session manager which solves this problem?

Comment: This is off-topic on SO I'm afraid, but in short, everybody should have a different keypair, and you are not supposed to "provide" the keypair to devs, they should create a keypair for themselves, and send you the public key which you would add to authorized_hosts. If somebody leaves, you just remove their public key.

Comment: It is like giving every employee in your company the username and password to a system: not a good idea. Because you cannot revoke individual access afterwards. Use ssm or use different key pairs.

Comment: Can we enable SSM and remove key access now

Answer (score 1):

When SSH is used to connect to a Linux computer, a **private keypair** is provided.

The Linux system will then check in the user's home directory for keys that are authorized to login. For example, if the user is `ec2-user`, it will look in `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If the matching **public keypair** is found, then the user is permitted to login.

Therefore, the recommended process is:

- Each user should **generate their own keypair**. They can do this in the EC2 management console, or on the command line using `ssh-keygen`. They should keep the private keypair to themselves, but provide an Admin with the public keypair. This is done to ensure that nobody else has ever seen the private keypair (it's like a password).
- The public keypair should be copied to Linux computer and added to the appropriate user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. This could be a shared user like `ec2-user`, or it could be a separate login for each user.
- If somebody leaves the company, simply **remove their keypair from the `authorized_keys` file**.

Since you have been using a shared keypair, you should remove that keypair immediately. Then, ask authorized users to create their own keypair, provide it to you, and then put them in the `authorized_keys` file.